# Copying files from one bucket to another bucket after Object deleted trigger in Cloud Storage (1st gen)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to copy files from one bucket to another bucket(Source bucket -> Backup Bucket) after object.delete event in cloud storage using cloud function.

I'm planning to do something like this

```py
import os
from google.cloud import storage

def copy_on_delete(event, context):
    # Get the source and destination bucket names from environment variables
    src_bucket_name = os.environ.get("SRC_BUCKET_NAME")
    dst_bucket_name = os.environ.get("DST_BUCKET_NAME")

    # Initialize the storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Get the source and destination buckets
    src_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(src_bucket_name)
    dst_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(dst_bucket_name)

    # Get the blob name from the event data
    blob_name = event["name"]

    # Get the source blob
    src_blob = src_bucket.get_blob(blob_name)

    # Copy the source blob to the destination bucket
    dst_blob = dst_bucket.copy_blob(src_blob, dst_bucket, blob_name)

    # Print a message
    print("Copied {src_blob.name} from {src_bucket.name} to {dst_blob.name} in {dst_bucket.name}")
```

deploy this function using this command:

`gcloud functions deploy copy_on_delete --trigger-bucket=SRC_BUCKET_NAME --trigger-event=google.storage.object.delete --set-env-vars SRC_BUCKET_NAME=mybucket-src,DST_BUCKET_NAME=mybucket-target --runtime python3`

This will create a Cloud Function that is triggered whenever an object is permanently deleted from the bucket named BUCKET_NAME.

Does this implementation works or is there any better approach ?

Comment: It won't work, you can't copy something that is already deleted

Comment: Instead of asking if some code works, you should actually run the code, and if it doesn't work, explain what it does that's different than what you expect, and share your debugging details.